# Connecting SourceShape/PortOpts from a UniformFanOutShape to sources in Akka Streams

Tags: akka-stream

Most examples of FanOut shapes in Akka steams either merge the faned-out flows into a single stream, or immediately connect them to a sink. I want to instead return a sequence of Sources that I can then apply transformation and connect to a sinks later on. An example would look something like this

```
def transformedSources(src: Source[Int,NotUsed]) : Seq[Source[Int,NotUsed]] {
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._
        val builder = new GraphDSL.Builder

        val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
        src.out ~> bcast.in

        val sourceShapes = (bcast.out).map {  out => SourceShape(out)}}
        ??? // How to convert sourceShapes into Sources
```

}

Is there a way to achieve this?

p.s
My real use case is an AmorphousShape that takes X sources, and produces X output. Ideally I would like to apply the AmorphousShape stage, and then continue operating as if nothing changes. 
So if my code now is

```
sources.map{s => s.via(someStage).runWith(Sink.seq)}
```

I would like to transform it into

```
transformSource(sources).map{s => s.via(someStage).runWith(Sink.seq)} 

def transformSource(sources:Seq[Source[Int, NotUsed]]) : Seq[Source[Int, NotUsed]] = {do some magic with an AmorphousShape graph }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the `transformSource` function is supposed to achieve? From a `Seq[Source]` you want to obtain a `Seq[Source]` of the same type, but with what changes?

Comment: @StefanoBonetti:I want to remove duplicate from the sources. First I consume the 1st source, then the 2nd, while removing all the items that have already been seen, etc.